# Sql instance is not opening in Windows azure

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I've deployed my version in windows azure.

After that I've added sql database. When I trying to connect, it doesn't allow from local. So I've clicked on **"Set up Windows Azure firewall rules for this IP address"** and added ip address. Now working fine when I run from local.

But When I tried to access from the iis8, I got an isssue is,

**A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - No such host is known.)
.Net SqlClient Data Provider**.

In local, the same functionality is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your server running IIS8 needs to be added to the firewall just like you did with your local machine, you can do this either using the Management Portal or you can connect to your SQL Azure instance from your local machine and run:

```
exec sp_set_firewall_rule N'IIS8 Webserver','X.Y.Z.0','X.Y.Z.0';
```

Where the first arguments is name of this firewall rule and X.Y.Z.0 is the public ip of your IIS8 Webserver.

The reason its specified two times is that you can specify a range of IP's.

[More info here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn270017.aspx)

Comment: Should I Execute in Sql Database - windows azure? Do I need to add network instance name?

Comment: Yes execute in your sql azure database no name is needed only ip the name specified can be anything

Comment: I"ve logged in windows azure portal. In sql databse, I've added virtual machine public ip address as allowed ip address.. still not working